# Can every DCFG be converted to DGNF?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, normal-forms

I know you can convert every context-free grammar into Greibach normal form grammar.

But can I convert every deterministic context-free grammar into deterministic Greibach normal form grammar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If by deterministic GNF you mean as a deterministic grammar that is also GNF then yes, here is the paper. [Normal forms of deterministic grammars](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X76800040)

> It is shown that every strict deterministic language may be given a
>   strict deterministic grammar which is also in Greibach normal form.

EDIT
Here is a paper outlining the technique to do the conversion [Strict deterministic grammars and Greibach normal form](http://doc.utwente.nl/66926/)